# Extract confidence interval values from ACF correlogram

Tags: r, correlation

In R, we can run an ACF correlogram of time series and the confidence interval bands will be plotted in light blue. But when I pull the structure of ACF object, I cannot find these values.  Does anyone know how to extract the values of the confidence interval bands?

e.g.

```
List of 6
 $ acf   : num [1:27, 1, 1] 1 0.06453 -0.06354 0.00213 -0.01324 ...
 $ type  : chr "correlation"
 $ n.used: int 501
 $ lag   : num [1:27, 1, 1] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
 $ series: chr "tser[i:(i + 500)]"
 $ snames: NULL
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "acf"
```

[image]

Comment: how do you plot your acf? which package are u suing?

Comment: I think it is built into stats package.  http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/acf.html

Answer (score 11):

I've had a look at the function and I can't see an easy way to extract the confidence interval. The region is calculated in the `plot.acf` function. To see this function, use

```
getS3method("plot", "acf")
```

In this function, there is a variable `clim`, this is the one you are after. The easiest way is to copy `plot.acf` to `myplot.acf`, but return the `clim` value.

Comment: thanks for that. It doesn't look like too easy of a task, but if I can't find any other way... I will have to try to modify the code.  Any quick posts on how exactly to modify would be appreciated.

Comment: @pat Just comment out the `return` statements and instead return `clim`

Comment: This should be accepted as the answer. Here is code to pull function: `dump("plot.acf",file = "function_dump_plot_acf.txt", envir=asNamespace("stats"))`. Also one need to replace `invisible()` with `return(clim)`

Comment: It would be useful if someone edited this answer to clearly show the code suggested by user1700890,including where to replace ```invisible()``` and what does the ```return(clim)```?

Answer (score 6):

I know this question is super old but if anyone does want the confidence interval values it's just the z-value of the confidence level divided by the sqrt of the number of observations used. In the `plot.acf` function this is calculated here:

```
clim0 <- if (with.ci) 
    qnorm((1 + ci)/2)/sqrt(x$n.used)
```

where `with.ci` is a logical value indicating if the user wants to plot the confidence intervals or not and `ci` is the desired confidence level (e.g. .95, .9, etc...)

EDIT: This is the confidence interval if you assume the lagged values are white noise, if this isn't the case there is a correction you can apply

```
clim <- clim0 * sqrt(cumsum(c(1, 2 * x$acf[-1, i, j]^2)))
```

You can read some more about that [here](http://www.pstat.ucsb.edu/faculty/feldman/174-03/lectures/l12.pdf)

Comment: The question might be super old, but this answer is super helpful too! So the confidence intervals are simply  $\pm \frac{z_{a/2}}{\sqrt{n}}$, where $a$ is the significance level and $n$ the size of the data.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so you have a series `X`, and you use the builtin [`stats::acf`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/acf) function to compute the autocorrelation function values.  To have a concrete example:

```
X     <- c(seq(20,10,-1),seq(1,20))
X_ACF <- acf(X) # by default the same as `acf(X, ci.type="white")`
```

You'll get a plot with confidence intervals at a constant value `acf(X, ci.type="white")` (for the default white-noise null hypothesis) or nonconstant value `acf(X, ci.type="ma")` (for a moving average assumption). *See documentation for [`plot.acf`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/plot.acf) for info on the difference.*

[image]

However, counterintuitively, the data for confidence intervals in those plots are *not* included in the object returned by `acf()`. But, you can still get them yourself pretty easily. To answer your question directly, **here is a function to get these confidence intervals from an "acf" object** (inspired by @csgillespie's suggestion):

```
get_clim <- function(x, ci=0.95, ci.type="white"){
  #' Gets confidence limit data from acf object `x`
  if (!ci.type %in% c("white", "ma")) stop('`ci.type` must be "white" or "ma"')
  if (class(x) != "acf") stop('pass in object of class "acf"')
  clim0 <- qnorm((1 + ci)/2) / sqrt(x$n.used)
  if (ci.type == "ma") {
    clim <- clim0 * sqrt(cumsum(c(1, 2 * x$acf[-1]^2))) 
    return(clim[-length(clim)])
  } else {
    return(clim0)
  }
}
```

Use it like

```
get_clim(X_ACF, ci.type = "white") # returns a single ci limit value (ci is plus or minus this value)
```

> ```
> [1] 0.3520199
> ```

```
get_clim(X_ACF, ci.type = "ma")    # returns a list of values, one per value of X_ACF$acf
```

> ```
>  [1] 0.3520199 0.5589558 0.6672833 0.7277000 0.7583282 0.7702831 0.7724234 0.7726377 0.7778812 0.7935320
> [11] 0.8225467 0.8650100 0.9061862 0.9443976
> ```

---

Now, to show that this worked, and since it may be useful, here's a function which makes [`ggplot2`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/index.html) plots corresponding to the default base R plots above.

```
library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_minimal())
ggplot_acf <- function(
    x,
    ci=0.95, ci.type="white", ci.col = "blue"){
  #' Replicates plot.acf() but using ggplot by default instead of base R plot
  #' `x` must be an object of class "acf" such as that outputted by `acf()`
  #' `ci.type` must be "white" or "ma"
  if (!ci.type %in% c("white", "ma")) stop('`ci.type` must be "white" or "ma"')
  if (class(x) != "acf") stop('pass in object of class "acf"')
  with.ci <- ci > 0 && x$type != "covariance"
  with.ci.ma <- with.ci && ci.type == "ma" && x$type == "correlation"
  if(with.ci.ma && x$lag[1L, 1L, 1L] != 0L) {
    warning("can use ci.type=\"ma\" only if first lag is 0")
    with.ci.ma <- FALSE
  }
  clim <- get_clim(x, ci=ci, ci.type=ci.type)
  df <- data.frame(lag = x$lag, acf=x$acf)
  p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=lag)) +
    geom_linerange(aes(ymax=acf, ymin=0)) +
    labs(y="ACF", x="Lag")
  if (with.ci) {
    if (ci.type == "white") {
      p <- p + 
        geom_hline(yintercept = 0-clim, lty = 2, col = ci.col) +
        geom_hline(yintercept = 0+clim, lty = 2, col = ci.col)
    } else if (with.ci.ma && ci.type == "ma") { # ci.type="ma" not allowed for pacf
      dfclim <- df[-1,]
      dfclim$clim <- clim
      p <- p + 
        geom_line(data = dfclim, aes(y = 0-clim), lty = 2, col = ci.col) +
        geom_line(data = dfclim, aes(y = 0+clim), lty = 2, col = ci.col)
    }
  }
  return(p)
}
```

To check that this is working, lets plot the resulting ggplot objects next to their corresponding base R plots made by `plot.acf`.

```
library(patchwork)
p11 <- ggplot_acf(X_ACF, ci.type="white") + labs(subtitle="ggplot version")
p12 <- wrap_elements(panel=~plot(X_ACF, ci.type="white"))  + labs(subtitle="base R version")

old_par <- par(mar = c(0,0,0,0), bg = NA)
(p11+p12) 
par(old_par)

p21 <- ggplot_acf(X_ACF, ci.type="ma") + labs(subtitle="ggplot version")
p22 <- wrap_elements(panel=~plot(X_ACF, ci.type="ma")) + labs(subtitle="base R version")

old_par <- par(mar = c(0,0,0,0), bg = NA)
(p21+p22) 
par(old_par)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: the function I made is inspired by @csgillespie 's suggestion to look in the source code for `plot.acf`, and I tried to keep it agnostic as to what kind of confidence interval you want, reflecting the assumption you have as your null hypothesis, as @matt-mills mentioned in their answer.

Comment: You can also use this to make Partial ACF plots like `ggplot_acf(pacf(X))`.