# Improving acf function and getting certain values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some problems connected with auto correlation function. Let's have a look at code following :

```
acf_plot<-function(vec,lag_max){
  val_acf <- acf(vec, plot = FALSE,lag.max = lag_max)
  df <- with(val_acf, data.frame(lag, acf))
  ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(x = lag, y = acf)) +
    geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0)) +
    geom_segment(mapping = aes(xend = lag, yend = 0))+ scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(-1,-0.75,-0.5,-0.25,0.25,0.50,0.75))
}

set.seed(20)
x<-runif(100)
acf(x)
acf_plot(vec=x,lag_max=30)
```

Function `acf_plot()` is creating acf function with respect to ggplot. The problem is during creation my confidence interval on the image is being omitted (You can see lack of blue line in the ggplot below).

[image]

[image]

To summarize I have two questions to you guys

(1) Is there any possibility to add blue line to that ggplot graph ? i.e. that confidence interval will be also included in acf ggplot.

(2) My second question is, how can I extract values of 95% confidence interval in acf ? I mean the exactly values behind those blue lines. I read [Extract confidence interval values from ACF correlogram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14266333/extract-confidence-interval-values-from-acf-correlogram) but I didn't get the point they were writing about. I tried to do it analogously but I failed. Can you guys help me with those two problems ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand the `stats:::plot.acf()` function, the confidence interval is calculated as `qnorm((1 + ci)/2) / sqrt(x$n.used)`, wherein `x` is the autocorrelation result. This makes sense to me since the values under i.i.d. noise assumptions are expected to follow a normal distribution. Hence, to plot the intervals you'd need to calculate the above in the function. Example below:

```r
library(ggplot2)

acf_plot<-function(vec,lag_max, ci = 0.95){
  val_acf <- acf(vec, plot = FALSE,lag.max = lag_max)
  df <- with(val_acf, data.frame(lag, acf))
  ci <- qnorm((1 + ci)/2) / sqrt(val_acf$n.used)
  
  ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(x = lag, y = acf)) +
    geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0)) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = c(-1, 1) * ci, linetype = 2, colour = "blue") +
    geom_segment(mapping = aes(xend = lag, yend = 0))+ 
    scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(-1,-0.75,-0.5,-0.25,0.25,0.50,0.75))
}

set.seed(20)
x<-runif(100)
acf(x)
```

[image]

```r
acf_plot(vec=x, lag_max=30)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-08-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Okey, So why there is only one confidence interval ? I mean I see only one blue line, and your code says that for each value different confidence interval is being calculated. I mean  `qnorm((1 + ci)/2) / sqrt(x$n.used)` suggests that number of confidence intervals should be equal to number of values acf function takes.

Comment: I'm not following how that line of code suggests that. `x$n.used` and `ci` are both scalars, so I'm unsure how that would result in a confidence interval for every input value.

Comment: Okey, what exactly is x$n.used ?

Comment: `x` is the list that the autocorrelation function returns, i.e. `x <- acf(runif(100))`, then `x$n.used` is `100` since there are 100 input values used.

Comment: Okey I understand now, what's the intuition behind taking last value to calculate confidence interval ?

Comment: It is not the last value, it is the number of values used as input. The `/ sqrt(x$n.used)` ensures that the confidence interval decreases as the number of samples increases, i.e. with more samples, you become more confident so the interval becomes smaller.

Comment: Okey now I understand. Calculation of confidence interval for pacf is analogous isn't it ?

Comment: Based on the code I'd say yes, but I don't know enough about pacf to be sure.

Comment: The constant confidence interval is just the default (`ci.type="white"`), you can also specify a moving average assumption as your by specifying `ci.type="ma"`.  See the end of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75366155/1676393) for a ggplot version of `acf.plot` that allows you to choose what type of confidence interval you want.  You can also use this same plotting function for `pacf` @John, though only the ci.type="white" is appropriate in that case, afaiu.