# error in R when using a for-loop to extract the list of significant coefficients of autocorrelation - time series

Tags: r, for-loop, time-series, confidence-interval, autocorrelation

I am trying to run a for-loop in order to create a list/ dataframe object that would give me the set of ACF coefficients that are significantly different to 0 (that are outside of the confidence interval). I am not too sure my for-loop does this, and anyways it gives me the following error message :

```
 Error in if (acf_res$ci[2, i + 1] < acf_res$acf[i + 1] || acf_res$ci[1,  : 
   missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Here is my current code, I am working on a univariate time series of electricity production from 1981 to 1999 included in France :

```
production_periode_1 <-periode_1$`Production brute d'électricité nucléaire (en GWh)`
prod_periode_1 <- ts(periode_1, frequency=12)
prod_periode_1 <- ts(production_periode_1, start=c(1981,1) , end=c(1999,12), 
frequency=12)
summary(prod_periode_1)
plot.ts(prod_periode_1)
plot(ts.union(prod_periode_1,log(prod_periode_1)))

acf(prod_periode_1,lag.max=150)
acf(diff(prod_periode_1),lag.max=150)
acf(diff(diff(prod_periode_1,12)),lag.max=150)


pacf(prod_periode_1, lag.max = 250)
pacf(diff(prod_periode_1), lag.max = 250)
pacf(diff(diff(prod_periode_1,12), lag.max = 250))


for (i in 1:228) {
  acf_res <- acf(prod_periode_1, lag.max = i, plot = FALSE)
  if (acf_res$ci[2, i+1] < acf_res$acf[i+1] || acf_res$ci[1, i+1] > acf_res$acf[i+1]) {
    print(paste("Coefficient significatif pour lag", i))
  } else {
    print(paste("Pas de coefficient significatif pour lag", i))
  }
}
```

Here is the structure of my dataset for reproducibility :

```
 structure(c(36509.514, 34485.002, 33702.518, 31274.906, 30241.116, 
 31542.381), tsp = c(1981, 1981.41666666667, 12), class = "ts")
```

I would be grateful for any advice !

Comment: The value of `acf_res$ci` is NULL. The `acf()` function returns an object of type `acf`. This class does not have a field called "ci". Please see `?acf` A confidence interval *is* shown when you plot an object of type `acf`. See also: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/211628/how-is-the-confidence-interval-calculated-for-the-acf-function

Comment: building on @br00ts comment: you can obtain the confidence intervals from `acf` like so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14266333/extract-confidence-interval-values-from-acf-correlogram or by using `Acf` (note capital A) from {forecast}.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a proposal using tidyverse which avoids a loop. The idea is to setup a tibble (a data.frame with additional features), compute the CI as done by `plot.acf()` and check CI exclusion using its columns.

```r
library(tidyverse)

theacf <- acf(prod_periode_1)

tibble(
  sample_ac = theacf$acf[, , 1],
  CI_lower = -qnorm(.975)/sqrt(length(prod_periode_1)),
  CI_upper = -CI_lower,
  significant = !between(sample_ac, CI_lower, CI_upper)
)
```

For your sample data, this yields

```
# A tibble: 6 × 4
  sample_ac CI_lower CI_upper significant
      <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl> <lgl>      
1    1        -0.800    0.800 TRUE       
2    0.495    -0.800    0.800 FALSE      
3    0.0157   -0.800    0.800 FALSE      
4   -0.403    -0.800    0.800 FALSE      
5   -0.426    -0.800    0.800 FALSE      
6   -0.181    -0.800    0.800 FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

This code calculates the 95% confidence interval if you assume that the lagged values are white noise:

```r
ci <- 0.95
prod_periode_1 <-  structure(c(36509.514, 34485.002, 33702.518, 31274.906, 30241.116, 
                               31542.381), tsp = c(1981, 1981.41666666667, 12), class = "ts")
summary(prod_periode_1)
plot.ts(prod_periode_1)
plot(ts.union(prod_periode_1,log(prod_periode_1)))

acf(prod_periode_1,lag.max=150)
acf(diff(prod_periode_1),lag.max=150)
# # acf(diff(diff(prod_periode_1,12)),lag.max=150)
# 
pacf(prod_periode_1, lag.max = 250)
pacf(diff(prod_periode_1), lag.max = 250)
# pacf(diff(diff(prod_periode_1,12), lag.max = 250))

for (i in 1:228) {
  message(i)
  lmm <- (length(prod_periode_1) - 1)
  if (i > lmm) {
    message(sprintf('lag.max max value of %s exceeded', lmm))
  } else {
    acf_res <- acf(prod_periode_1, lag.max = i, plot = FALSE)
    clim0 <- qnorm((1 + ci) / 2) / sqrt(acf_res$n.used)
    if ((-clim0 > acf_res$acf[ i + 1 ]) || (clim0 < acf_res$acf[ i + 1 ])) {
      print(sprintf('Coefficient significatif pour lag.max %s', i))
    } else {
      print(sprintf('Pas de coefficient significatif pour lag.max %s', i))
    }  
  }
}
```

Comment: I am not convinced by this code : indeed, when I try to run the code on my series differentiated in seasonality and in trend (replacing prod_periode_1 by diff(diff(prod_periode_1,12)), it indicates that all coefficients are significant, whereas the ACF plot indicates many that are in the confidence interval ie not significantly different to 0. This is because I get the following error message : Error in if (-clim0 < acf_res$acf[i + 1] || clim0 > acf_res$acf[i + 1]) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: Apologies, I pasted an incorrect version of the code. The post has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering is due to missing values in the confidence interval (acf_res$ci). This happens when the ACF calculation does not provide confidence intervals for certain lags. To address this issue, you can modify your code to skip the missing values when checking for significance. Here's an updated version of your for-loop:

```
for (i in 1:228) {
  acf_res <- acf(prod_periode_1, lag.max = i, plot = FALSE)
  if (!is.na(acf_res$ci[2, i+1]) && !is.na(acf_res$ci[1, i+1])) {
    if (acf_res$ci[2, i+1] < acf_res$acf[i+1] || acf_res$ci[1, i+1] > acf_res$acf[i+1]) {
      print(paste("Coefficient significatif pour lag", i))
    } else {
      print(paste("Pas de coefficient significatif pour lag", i))
    }
  } else {
    print(paste("Intervalles de confiance manquants pour lag", i))
  }
}
```

In this updated code, we first check if the confidence interval values at the specified lag (acf_res$ci[2, i+1] and acf_res$ci[1, i+1]) are missing (NA). If they are not missing, we proceed with the significance check as before. If they are missing, we print a message indicating that the confidence intervals are not available for that lag.

This modification should prevent the "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed" error and provide more informative feedback when confidence intervals are missing.